# How to find the intersection point of rect and a line starting in its center?

Tags: swift, geometry

I need to find the point (green dot) on the edges of any (not just squares) given rectangle (grey box) where a line(red line) starting from the centre of the rectangle would intersect the rectangle.

[image: visualization]

The function should look something like this:

```
func intersection(forAngle angle: CGFloat, rect: CGRect) -> CGPoint {
   // Do magic here
}
```

[gist](https://gist.github.com/densmoe/6f764c981249f09eb74f309f6e950f37) for easy visualisation that you can paste into a macOS playground

This is what I have so far:

```
let t = tan(angle)
switch angle {
case 0..<(pi/2):
  //top right corner - works but only for square rects
  // t > 1 => top edge, t < 1 right edge
  let x = t > 1 ? rect.width + (1 - t) * rect.width / 2 : rect.width
  let y = t < 1 ? t * rect.height / 2 + rect.height / 2 : rect.height
  return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
case (pi/2)..<pi:
  //top left corner
case pi..<(1.5*pi):
  //bottom left corner
case 1.5*pi..<2*pi:
  //bottom right corner
default:
  return CGPoint.zero
}
```

Comment: Have you done *anything* in an attempt to solve this problem?

Comment: @ScottHunter I tried to break down the rectangle into 4 corners and use tan, but I couldn't really get it to work for more than one side or non-squares (see edit)

Comment: All the math you need, and an Objective-C solution, are explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9526726/77567