# Get End CGPoint() of Arc

Tags: ios, swift3, core-animation, uibezierpath

I am creating arc with below line

```
func drawSomething(_ context: CGContext, rect: CGRect) {
    context.saveGState()
    let path = UIBezierPath()

    let pathStartRagAngle = (0).degreesToRadians
    let pathEndRagAngle = (220).degreesToRadians

    path.addArc(withCenter: centerS, radius: rangeLabelsRect.size.width / 2.0, startAngle: CGFloat(pathStartRagAngle), endAngle: CGFloat(pathEndRagAngle - 0.01), clockwise: true)
    let color =  UIColor.red
    color.setStroke()
    path.lineWidth = rangeLabelsWidth
    path.stroke()
}
```

Gave this result 
  [image]

what I wanted to do is add circle to end of red arc, for that I need CGPoint. so could find any way to do it,

Comment: you question is little bit not clear, will you need degree conversion from user touched CGPoint ?

Comment: @Ammaiappan I want CGPoint where red arc close

Comment: It may help your needs https://stackoverflow.com/a/9527985/529294

Answer (score 1):

`UIBezierPath` has a `currentPoint` property which will be at the end of the last component you added to the path. That should work for you.